# How to use this json with angular datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, datatables, angular-datatables

This is my server response.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [{
    "id": null,
    "reportType": "Total Voucher Report",
    "reportModule": "Vouchers",
    "reportData": [{
        "id": "1",
        "voucherPackId": "2",
        "serialNumber": "0",
        "status": "Free",
        "isBlocked": "N",
        "voucherPin": "0",
        "buyDate": null,
        "redeemDate": null,
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "statusCode": null,
        "identifier": "MCM0007532",
        "merchantName": "test1",
        "voucherName": "fddf",
        "expiryDate": "2016-02-24 00:00:00",
        "dealCategory": "Hotels \u0026 Travel",
        "shortDescription": "xvxv",
        "voucherWorth": "33.00"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "voucherPackId": "2",
        "serialNumber": "0",
        "status": "Free",
        "isBlocked": "N",
        "voucherPin": "0",
        "buyDate": null,
        "redeemDate": null,
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "statusCode": null,
        "identifier": "MCM0007532",
        "merchantName": "test1",
        "voucherName": "fddf",
        "expiryDate": "2016-02-24 00:00:00",
        "dealCategory": "Hotels \u0026 Travel",
        "shortDescription": "xvxv",
        "voucherWorth": "33.00"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "voucherPackId": "2",
        "serialNumber": "0",
        "status": "Free",
        "isBlocked": "N",
        "voucherPin": "0",
        "buyDate": null,
        "redeemDate": null,
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "statusCode": null,
        "identifier": "MCM0007532",
        "merchantName": "test1",
        "voucherName": "fddf",
        "expiryDate": "2016-02-24 00:00:00",
        "dealCategory": "Hotels \u0026 Travel",
        "shortDescription": "xvxv",
        "voucherWorth": "33.00"
    }]
}],
"message": null}
```

I used it as,

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
        .newOptions()
        .withOption('ajax', {
            url: config.base_url + 'report/voucher?module=Vouchers&type=Total Voucher Report&merchant=1',
            type: 'POST',
            dataSrc: 'data.data[0].reportData[0]',
        })
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withBootstrap()
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

It says invalid JSON response. Appreciate your kindly help. 
Debug result: http://debug.datatables.net/urizon

Comment: Here is the debugger result. http://debug.datatables.net/urizon

Answer (score 1):

Use the following value for [`dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option: `data[0].reportData` as shown below. Also you need to remove `serverSide` and `processing` options since your data doesn't have correct structure for server-side processing mode.

You also need to define columns structure since you're using array of objects as your data source.

```js
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
        .newOptions()
        .withOption('ajax', {
            url: config.base_url + 'report/voucher?module=Vouchers&type=Total Voucher Report&merchant=1',
            type: 'POST',
            dataSrc: 'data[0].reportData'
        })
        .withBootstrap()
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

vm.dtColumns = [
    /* List data properties for each column in the table. */
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('voucherPackId'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('serialNumber'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('status')        
];
```

Comment: Yes - though, the "by the book" angular dataTables notation would be `.fromSource(config.base_url + 'report/voucher?module=Vouchers&type=Total Voucher Report&merchant=1').withDataProp('data[0].reportData');`

Comment: @davidkonrad, Thanks for the note. Seems like both could be used, see [server-side processing example](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing), especially when OP wants to use POST method.

Comment: Yes, they are just shorthands for  `.withOption('ajax'` etc - no problem with your suggestion at all. I am not sure OP actually _wants_ to use `type: 'POST'`, how would it ever be of any use in this setup? Most of the times `type: 'POST'` seems to be a result of copy paste / cargo cult programming - not in there for any reason.

Comment: @davidkonrad, I agree. But you never know what server-side requirements are, sometimes you need to use POST indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If your use a parser your will get error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 63 column 16 of the JSON data. So yes **your JSON is invalid** ! Just add } on list line. Because every brackets need to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JSON response has `Content-Type: application/json` header, otherwise it might not be parsed correctly.

Comment: Ya it has the content type.